# Ambient occlusion problem using EEVEE

Tags: eevee-render-engine, compositing-nodes, ambient-occlusion

I'm trying EEVEE for compositing but I don't know how to avoid (if possible) those ambient occlusion "pops" . It occurs when an object is in front of other and the ao shadows appear suddenly when revealed to the camera.

[image: No AO shadow in this frame, but in the next one...]

[image: ... the ao shadow appears suddenly]

Comment: have you given AO to these objects and have enabled AO in the Render panel.

Comment: Not sure what do you mean saying "given AO to these objects" Have I to do something with the objects? Is it not enough activating AO in the View layer panel? In Cycles I don't have to modify objects to get tha AO pass... is with EEVEE different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for this happening is that unlike cycles, ambient occlusion generated by evvee are not physically accurate. Eevee tries to mimic ambient occlusion and only generates ambient occlusion for objects in front of the camera.

As you said, ambient occlusion pops occurs when an object which was hidden by something comes in front of the camera. It is coz as soon as the object is visible to camera, eevee generates ambient occlusion causing the poping effect.

My advice would be to use cycles which generates physically accurate Ao maps

Comment: So AO is useless but for still images in EEVEE. Thanks, Maulik